# show regular and special price separately

Tags: magento-1.9, tierprice, special-price

I'm trying to separate normal price and special price on my **catalog/product/view.phtml page.**
I want to display them like this:

> Retail Price: £5.99   Trade Price: £4.09

It's currently set up like this:

```
<div class="price-info">
<p class="retailprice"> Retail Price : </p><?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product); ?>
</div>
```

But it seems **getPriceHtml($_product);** gets both normal and special price so I'm unable to separate them.
I can only get it to look like this:

> Retail Price: £5.99
>    £4.09
>    Trade Price:

Ive tried this - which I hashed together from various other answers here

```
<div class="price-info">
<p class="retailprice"> Retail Price : </p><?php echo $_product->getRegularPrice(); ?>
<p class="specialprice"> Special Price: </p><?php echo $_product->getSpecialPrice(); ?>
</div>
```

But this is just showing blank.

Ideally I would actually like the regular retail price to come from another store view price and trade price to be the regular price of a second store view - but I can work around that with catalog price rules it if that is not possible.

Apologies for the convoluted question, i know 0 PHP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get product price by store id, use below code for that (regular retail price to come from another store view, i.e. as per store id):

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->setStoreId($storeId)->load($key);

echo Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice($product->getPrice());
```

Now you can use the same code for getting price from second store, as per your question.

Answer (score 0):

This seemed to work for getting the prices separately

Get normal price:

```
<?php echo Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice($_product->getPrice()); ?>
```

Get final(special Price):

```
<?php echo Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice($_product->getFinalPrice()); ?>
```

not exactly sure why I needed to use 'checkout' tho